# Installing ArchLinux into Ubuntu 12.04 root

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, arch-linux

Is it possible to install 2 linux distros into 1 root, so they share same uuid and guid, configs and packages + same user /home folder ? For example: I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 already in dual boot on my laptop. Could I install Arch's base, base-devel and kernel, so it won't conflict with Ubuntu on the same root folder?
P.S I don't feel like repartitioning my drive again, 'cause there's very complicated hierarchy, which occupies the entire disk. =)

Answer (score 1):

Sharing packages is not possible: Ubuntu and Arch use different packaging systems. And Arch's `/etc` would overwrite Ubuntu's `/etc` (or vice-versa), destroying one (or both) of the systems in the process.

However, you can share /home between distros by putting it in a separate partition and then adding an entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install multiple Linux on a hard drive, but you must comply with minimum restrictions:

A. - Each must have a Linux root partition: Because they use a different package manager and information of different versions of installed packages. If you share the root partition, you risk breaking the system consistency.
2. - You can use a boot partition and a swap partition for multiple Linux shared.